# WAMP: requests suddenly take upwards of 40s to respond

Tags: wamp

As the title says, I have been using WAMP for my local development server with no issues to speak of until yesterday.

I haven't changed anything but to be on the safe side I re-installed wamp. The issue persists.

[image]

In the above image you can see that initially it loads fine, but then suddenly it begins crawling.

There are a few things I should note:

- The PHP pages return data from an amazon RDS MySQL instance
- The production site (which uses the same DB - I know it's bad practice) is running perfectly
- This phenomenon occurs on all pages of my site
- Requests sometimes respond sooner than those
  made earlier
- Response times seem to increasing with time (in the time it took me to write this they have increased to 5 minutes
- WAMP CPU usage seems normal

I would appreciate your advice

Comment: Timing out trying to do DNS lookups of the client(s) connecting?  Are DNS names or IPs logged in the apache access/error log? Anything in hte PHP code looking at client DNS names?

Comment: The weird thing is that the requests don't time out. They just wait for a response, even if it takes 5 minutes. To your other questions, no DNS names or IPs are being logged, nor does the PHP code have any dealings with them. The PHP page is a simple API.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking your PHP code? "The PHP pages return data from an amazon RDS MySQL instance" tells me that the Amazon instance is taking a long time to respond or you might have been rate-limited or something.

Comment: If you run fiddler or other analysis tools, are the browser/clients getting a header and then the wait starts, or do they wait for any output at all?  If they are getting a header, that may explain the lack of a timeout (but not the slowness)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I've looked at the result of Xdebug's profiler and nothing seems out of the ordinary